# Returning strings contained within blocks of text, without punctuation attached

Tags: python, regex, text

I need to match and return any word containing at least one of the strings/combinations of characters below:

```
- tion (as in navigation, isolation, or mitigation)
- ex (as in explanation, exfiltrate, or expert)
- ph (as in philosophy, philanthropy, or ephemera)
- ost, ist, ast (as in hostel, distribute, past)
```

My function appears to do this

```
TEXT_SAMPLE = """
Striking an average of observations taken at different times-- rejecting those
timid estimates that gave the object a length of 200 feet, and ignoring those
exaggerated views that saw it as a mile wide and three long--you could still
assert that this phenomenal creature greatly exceeded the dimensions of
anything then known to ichthyologists, if it existed at all.
Now then, it did exist, this was an undeniable fact; and since the human mind
dotes on objects of wonder, you can understand the worldwide excitement caused
by this unearthly apparition. As for relegating it to the realm of fiction,
that charge had to be dropped.
In essence, on July 20, 1866, the steamer Governor Higginson, from the
Calcutta & Burnach Steam Navigation Co., encountered this moving mass five
miles off the eastern shores of Australia.
"""

def latin_ish_words(text):

    #Returns input text into list of words, splitting on whitespace, allocates list to text_list 
    text_list = text.split()
    #Creates an empty string, match_list
    match_list = []
    #Creates a string containing latinish featurs
    part_list = ["tion", "ex", "ph", "ost", "ist", "ast"]
    #Iterates through list of words and latinish features, adds word to match_list if contains latinish features
    for word in text_list:
        for part in part_list:
            if part in word:
                match_list.append(word)
    match_list = list(dict.fromkeys(match_list))
    return match_list

latin_ish_words(TEXT_SAMPLE)
```

```
['observations', 'exaggerated', 'phenomenal', 'exceeded', 'ichthyologists,', 'existed', 'exist,', 'excitement', 'apparition.', 'fiction,', 'Navigation', 'eastern']
```

However, when numbers have punctuation attached, the function will also return punctuation

E.g - exist,',

How could one filter out such attached punctuation?

Comment: Your question is very unclear since your regex matches numbers and you show the output containing words.

Comment: if you want to clear punctuation, you need to pre process your text to remove the same.

Comment: Please next time try to make your example [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. minimizing `TEXT_SAMPLE` (e.g.3 lines, each containing 4 words) should be enough to show the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use `r"\b\w*(?:tion|ex|ph|ost|ist|ast)\w*\b"` regex. Explanation (see also [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)):

- `\b` ... word boundary
- `\w` ... word character
- `*` ... 0 or more repetition
- `\w*` ... 0 or more word characters
- `(?:...)` ... "plain" parens, not creating a group
- `|` ... or
- `tion|ex|ph` ... `tion` or `ex` or `ph`

Code:

```py
import re
print(re.findall(r"\b\w*(?:tion|ex|ph|ost|ist|ast)\w*\b",TEXT_SAMPLE))
```

For convenience, you can build the pattern programtically, adding the parts from a variable:

```py
import re
part_list = [
    "tion", 
    "ex", 
    "ph", 
    "ost", 
    "ist", 
    "ast",
]
part_re = "|".join(part_list)
pattern = fr"\b\w*(?:{part_re})\w*\b"
# pattern = r"\b\w*(?:{})\w*\b".format(part_re) # for older versions not allowing f-string syntax
print(re.findall(pattern,TEXT_SAMPLE))
```

Output:

```
[
   'observations',
   'exaggerated',
   'phenomenal',
   'exceeded',
   'ichthyologists',
   'existed',
   'exist',
   'excitement',
   'apparition',
   'fiction',
   'Navigation',
   'eastern',
]
```